# Android: Stop a handler at a certain time in an Intent Service

Tags: android, performance, android-handler

I have an intentService that starts a handler, but after a certain amount of time I need to stop the handler. I'm not sure how to do this. I have the class below, but I'm just not sure how to stop the handler once the time is reached, or when a certain amount of hours/min passes. I would like this to be as efficient as possible please.

```
public class RedirectService extends IntentService {

   private Handler handler;
   private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           foobar();
           handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
       }
   };

   public LockedRedirectService() {
       super("RedirectService");
   }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent redirectIntent) {
       // Gets data from the incoming Intent
       int hour = redirectIntent.getIntExtra("hour", 0);
       int min = redirectIntent.getIntExtra("minute", 0);



       handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
       handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new thread and wait. When time's up, stop and remove the runnable.
Or use handler to post another delayed runnable to stop and remove the working runnable.

```
    public class RedirectService extends IntentService {

    private Handler handler;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mRun) {
                foobar();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        }
    };

    public LockedRedirectService() {
        super("RedirectService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent redirectIntent) {
        // Gets data from the incoming Intent
        final int hour = redirectIntent.getIntExtra("hour", 0);
        final int min = redirectIntent.getIntExtra("minute", 0);


        mRun = true;
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
        //handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((hour * 60 + min) * 60 * 1000);
                } catch (Exception ignore) {}
                mRun = false;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
           }
        }).start();

        /* or use handler
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mRun = false;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
           }
        }, (hour * 60 + min) * 60 * 1000);
        */
    }

    }
```